# Safari app is not opening from dock icon

Tags: safari

What could be happening? Was after latest OSX update.

Seems the app is not responding but is installed.

[image]

Still unsolved!

Answer (score -1):

You should try to launch the app with command line.

```
/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari &
```

Comment: Ok, it's working, so what's happening? I would like to launch from the icon too.

Comment: Maybe create a batch file containing this command ?
Else, did you try to uninstall/install Safari ? (or update it)

Comment: How to uninstall/install Safari?

Comment: Go in your Application folder (from Finder), and drag the app in the trash. Then, download it from the App Store and install it.

Comment: Seems can't. “Safari.app” can’t be modified or deleted because it’s required by OS X.

Comment: I created terminal command shortcut icon, as here describes: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3175771?start=0&tstart=0